# Calculating a sum $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(1-p)^i}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, summation, solution-verification

I want to calculate this sum, while $0<p<1$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(1-p)^i}$$

Is this correct:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(1-p)^i}=\frac{1}{1-p}\cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1-p)^k}}{1-\frac{1}{1-p}}=\frac{1-(1-p)^k}{p(1-p)^k}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(1-p)^i}
&=&\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^{i-1}\cr
&=&\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^{j}\cr
&=&\frac{1}{1-p}\cdot\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^{k-1}}{1-\frac{1}{1-p}}\cr
&=&-\frac{1}{p}\left[1-\frac{1}{(1-p)^{k-1}}\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for that! :)